# Dealing with a good faith, but inaccurate reviewer of edits

Tags: support

For the edit review:

[image: MATLAB]

The reviewing user seems unaware that the correct title for MATLAB utilises all caps and has erroneously designated the edit according to their error. How best to make the user aware of their error for future, given no direct messaging, and no ability to leave a direct comment on a Stack Overflow review summary?

Comment: The reviewer rejected the edit for the wrong reason.  Your suggestion is not spam (which can carry extra penalties).  I could see it being rejected as "no improvement" per reviewer but that's completely different than spam/vandalism.

Comment: @ryanyuyu since when do edits rejected as spam carry extra penalties?  did I miss a major change on that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reviewer is the post owner. You can just ping under his post.

I wouldn't worry too much. This user rejecting one edit isn't worth making a whole story of. Sometimes just accept users make mistakes.

Comment: I'll let him know MATLAB is the correct abbreviation and resubmit. If it gets rejected again it'll go against my record, but at least for the right reasons, though in my opinion it is a significant improvement.